# Can information about a drug - trade name, interactions, etc. - be copyright protected?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, medical

Can information about a drug, like its trade name, interactions, pharmacokinetics, etc., be copyright protected, or is the information free for use in a commercial sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information itself is not copyrighted.

- The fact that a drug is an "antagonist platelet aggregation inhibitor" is not copyrighted.
- The fact that a drug is indicated for "reducing the risk of thrombotic stroke in patients who have experienced stroke precursors or who have had a completed thrombotic stroke" is not copyrighted.

The label author might make certain choices about how to express those facts, though. "[C]hoices as to selection and arrangement, so long as they are made independently by the compiler and entail a minimal degree of creativity, are sufficiently original" to trigger copyright protection. [Feist Pubs., Inc. v. Rural Tel. Svc. Co., Inc.](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/499/340/case.html).

The FDA has created regulations concerning the selection and arrangement of facts in the context of prescription drug labeling. ([An Introduction to the
Improved FDA Prescription
Drug Labeling](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Training/ForHealthProfessionals/UCM090796.pdf), [21 CFR Part 201](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfCFR/CFRSearch.cfm?CFRPart=201), [Consolidated Final Rule and Changes](http://www.fda.gov/OHRMS/DOCKETS/98fr/06-545.pdf))

Thus in the context of prescription drug labeling, the selection and arrangement of facts are not "made independently by the compiler".

The only things this leaves for copyright protection are:

- literal word-for-word copying of phrases where there are suitable alternative ways of expressing the same fact, or
- other expression not regulated by the FDA.

And, if a certain mode of expressing a particular fact has become industry standard (even if there are alternatives), the *scènes à faire* doctrine either precludes copyrightability or is a defense to infringement, depending on your district.